# How to display Woocommerce Products prices in Bitcoin or Satoshis?

Tags: exchange-rate, websites, website-integration, ecommerce

In a WooCommerce website, we aim to display the product prices in satoshi/bitcoin based on the current market value. Ideally we don't want to use any existing plugin and we are looking to get the updated market value from Coingecko or any other free API.

There's an easy way to do it? Maybe with a script to be added in the `child-theme/functions.php`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up building **Bitcoin Price Converter**, a plugin for WordPress and compatible with WooCommerce

Converts WooCommerce product prices to Bitcoin using exchange rates.

- Custom settings available from the admin sidebar menu  `Woocommerce > Bitcoin Converter` .
- Select your preferred denomination (BTC, mBTC, sats)
- Select to display fiat price, Bitcoin price or both
- Select API price source between CoinGecko, Coindesk or your custom source

For more info:

**Repo** on [GitHub](https://GitHub.com/SuperAtic-LABS/bitcoin-price-converter)

**Demo** web [site](https://veintiuno.world/m/digitales/bitcoin-price-converter-woocommerce-plugin/)

**Donate** on [Geyser](https://geyser.fund/project/bitcoinpriceconverterwordpressplugin)

.